# Problems with dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have this function

```
string F(dynamic a)
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

later when i say

```
dynamic a = 5;
var result = F(a);
```

result must be in compilation time a string type, but that not happened, why?
In fact, the compilar pass this

```
int result2 = F(a);
```

and not this

```
int result3 = F(5);
```

Anything help please?

Comment: Do you have any overloads of `F`?

Comment: Something is not adding up here. You've declared a string return type and are, in fact, returning a string. So I do not see how it is possible that you are getting an int result.

Comment: Recreating his program, the intellisense tells me that `result` is dynamic too

Comment: @Jonesy that is... interesting.

Comment: @Chris wouldn't overloads have to have the same return type?

Comment: here we go, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829518/c-sharp-dynamic-parameter-causes-compiler-to-think-method-return-is-dynamic). Mainly, `dynamic stops the compiler from knowing the type on any parameters, properties, or method return types`

Comment: @Brian No - overloads can return different types, so long as the compiler is able to differentiate them through different arguments

Comment: Thanks @JamesThorpe, and I realized what you said after I asked the question as well.

Comment: What do you mean by _"result must be in compilation time a string type, but that not happened, why?"_? What does your compiler say exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829518/c-sharp-dynamic-parameter-causes-compiler-to-think-method-return-is-dynamic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is explained in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx):

> Overload resolution occurs at run time instead of at compile time if one or more of the arguments in a method call have the type dynamic, or if the receiver of the method call is of type dynamic.

Now in the case of `F(a)` since a is dynamic, compiler doesn't check for the overloads at compile-time. But when you say:

```
F(2);
```

`2` is an integer and not `dynamic`. That's why the overload resolution occurs at compile time and you get the error.If you cast the integer literal to dynamic you won't get any error at compile time (but you do on run-time):

```
int x = F((dynamic)2);
```

Comment: @BlueMonkMN if there is no overload that returns an int then an exception will occur at runtime.

Comment: As I expected. I'm just being a stickler over the phrase "you won't get any error." This looks like good evidence to support the position that dynamic typing leads to more error-prone code.