# "dynamic" keyword with builder pattern hides extension method

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, extension-methods

I have recently come across a strange behavior with the `dynamic` keyword whilst I was testing something. This isn't a problem I desperately need solving as I was just experimenting, but I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on what was happening

I have a builder which returns an `HttpWebRequest` object and an extension method on `HttpWebRequest`.

One of my builder methods takes a `string` argument. The whole thing works when I pass the builder method a string, but I pass it a `dynamic` variable which is a string it no longer works.

It appears as if the builders method which should return type `HttpWebRequestBuilder` now returns `dynamic`.

The code below is a simple was to reproduce it and is also available [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2bZLhH)

**Note**

To make it work, comment out the line `.SetBody(dynamicString)` and uncomment the line `.SetBody(json)`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic dynamicString = "{ \"test\" : \"value\" }";
        string json = "{ \"test\" : \"value\" }";

        string test = new HttpWebRequestBuilder()
            .SetRequestType()
            //.SetBody(json) //uncomment this and it works
            .SetBody(dynamicString) //uncomment this and it breaks
            .Build()
            .ExtensionMethod();

        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }

}

public class HttpWebRequestBuilder
{
    private readonly HttpWebRequest _request;

    public HttpWebRequestBuilder() 
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        _request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    }

    public HttpWebRequestBuilder SetRequestType() 
    {
        _request.Method = "POST";
        _request.ContentType = "application/json";

        return this;
    }

    public HttpWebRequestBuilder SetBody(string json) 
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        _request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream writer = _request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        return this;
    }

    public HttpWebRequest Build() 
    {
        return _request;
    }
}

public static class WebRequestExtensions 
{
    public static string ExtensionMethod(this HttpWebRequest webRequest) 
    {
        return "extension method worked";
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is something strange with the way `dynamic` objects work. But any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because passing a `dynamic` parameter makes C# compiler treat the return type of the expression, i.e. `.SetBody(dynamicString)`, as `dynamic` (relevant [explanation of method return types with dynamic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7829518/335858)).

Extension methods work with `dynamic` objects only as regular methods, not as extension methods (see [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313149/335858) for an explanation of this), hence the compile-time error that you see.

Comment: i read that answer of eric in past, but i totally forgot about it  :/

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer of dasblinkenlight seems to be right, please remember that you can always avoid this issue by reformulating your code in this way:

```
public class Program
{        public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic dynamicString = "{ \"test\" : \"value\" }";
        string json = "{ \"test\" : \"value\" }";

        var test = new HttpWebRequestBuilder();
            test.SetRequestType();
            //test.SetBody(json); //still works
            test.SetBody(dynamicString); // works also now
            var b = test.Build();
            var s = b.ExtensionMethod();

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had actually done something similar to get around when I was testing. The question was more for me to understand why it was happening. This could be helpful for someone else so I will give up a +1